# jQuery Operator for NOT

Tags: jquery

I am sure must be a simple question but I am not quite sure what I am looking for.
I would simply like to test is it is NOT MSIE browser, then do something.

How would I write a basic if NOT MSIE then in jQuery?

Comment: you already have the answer in your question, if NOT msie, then run code... => if (!$.browser.msie).

Comment: So you know, browser sniffing is evil.  Stop it.  It's not that hard to write cross-browser compatible code, especially when you're already using jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I think the phrasing of my question was not clear. What I was looking for was the operator for NOT in jQuery. But at the time of this question I didn't even know the term "operator". Rephrasing now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (!$.browser.msie)
```

Add a "not" before the conditional.

Answer (score 3):

Should be as simple as

```
if (!$.browser.msie)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!$.browser.msie)
```

Should do it!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this.

This replaces the html tag with one that either contains an msie class or not.

```
<!--[if IE]>    <html class="msie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

and in your javascript:

```
if (!$("html").is("msie")) {
  alert("Thank you for making the world a better place!");
}
```

the $.browser method is depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1) {
//it is ie
}

or


if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") == -1) {
//it is not ie
}
```

Comment: Someday i'm gonna build a browser that randomly sticks "not MSIE" in the user-agent string, and then file bug reports just to screw around with people who think they have to know what browser i'm running.

Comment: you can also use the tilde and a not: `!~navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie")` . `~-1` = `0`, `!0` = `true`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with this,

```
 if (!$.browser.msie) {
    alert( "this is your code placeholder!" );
  }
```